# Solitaire Chess

Tags: strategy, chess, no-computers

A friend of mine got me [Solitaire Chess](http://www.thinkfun.com/microsite/solitairechess/demo) for Christmas years ago. I set up the board below. Is it possible to solve it? If so, what is the solution? (No programs allowed- Use only your brain.)

**Rules:**

> 1. Pieces move as in regular chess
> 2. Every move must be a capture
> 3. When there is only 1 piece left, you win.

[image]

Comment: which way are the pawns moving ? do they "promote" if they hit the far side ?

Comment: they are moving up, and they do not promote

Comment: It'd be **a lot harder** if rule 3 required a pawn to be the sole survivor. (Not possible?)Looks like many solutions exist and almost any of the "pieces" can be the last one. Haven't found B2 being last yet.

Comment: @user2338816 ending with a pawn is not possible. d4 must be taken (as cannot take anything) and b2 must be taken by Ba3 (otherwise there will be a piece on a3 that cannot take or be taken)

Comment: One of the puzzles I had encountered in the book had 1 non-capturing move.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's go with:

> Nxa1, Bxc4, Rxc4, Rxd4, Bxb2, Bxd4, Bxa1

Answer (score 23):

Here are my thoughts on the matter:

Want to end with a knight?

> Bb3, Bb2, Bc3, Bd4, Rd4, Nb3, Nd4

Want to end with a rook?

> Bb3, Bb2, Bc3, Bd4, Nb3, Nd4, Rd4

Want to end with a bishop?

> Bb3, Nb3, Nd4, Bb2, Bc3, Rd4, Bd4

Want to keep from having to move your horses from the stables?

> Bb3, Bb2, Bc4, Rc4, Rd4, Ba1, Bd4

Do you want to end on a square other than D4?

> Bb3, Bc4, Rc4, Rd4, Bb2, Bd4, Ba1

Yeah.... I think there might be a few solutions...

Answer (score 6):

I got

> Bb2, Bb3, Rc4, Rd4, Bd4, Nb3, Nd4

Answer (score 4):

Different from the other two

> Nxb3, Nxd4, Bxb2, Bxc4, Rxc4, Rxd4, Bxd4

Answer (score 3):

What an interesting game. Thanks for sharing this.

Here's the first solution I found:

> Bxb3, Nxb3, Bxb2, Bxc3, Bxd4, Rxd4, Nxd4

Note: for those who haven't seen the move notation before, "Bd1" or "Bxd1" means "move the bishop to square 'd1.'"
B=bishop, N=knight, R=rook, P=pawn, K=king, Q=queen

Answer (score 2):

If pawns moving "down"

> Pxc3
>  Pxa1 (promote to anything you want)
>  Rxc3
>  Rxb3
>  Rxa3
>  Rxa2
>  Rxa1

If pawns moving "up"

> Rxd4
>  Bxb2
>  Bxb3
>  Rxb3
>  Nxb3
>  Bxd4
>  Nxd4

Comment: As far as I know, the Pawn can't move down, but I like the idea of promotion!

Comment: Convention implies white starts at bottom and moves up, however, with this odd "unconventional" board .. it warranted asking ;)

Answer (score 2):

Power to the church! (Bishops)

> Bb2, Ba1, Bb3, Bc4, Rc4, Rd4, Bd4

Answer (score 2):

I got:

> Bb2 Bc3 Bd4 Bb3 Nb3 Nd4 Rd4

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question?

Comment: Sure, I did it in my head and I couldn't find my solution in the given answers. But that's probably not the explanation you're looking for - I'm not sure what you'd like to hear.. So: B on a3 can only go to P on b2, so it was a logical first move (same goes for N on a1 but then we still need B on a2 to be taken), as I was already moving B from a3 I continued to d4, then with most pieces gone it was trivial PS: if that's what you're looking for I'll edit the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I found in about 5 min (I m pretty proud of myself considering that I'm not so good at chess)

> BxB2,BxC3,BxD4,BxB3,NxB3,RxD4,NxD4