# Solitaire Chess- Round 2

Tags: strategy, chess

This is another [Solitaire Chess](http://www.thinkfun.com/microsite/solitairechess/demo) puzzle like [this earlier puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11242/solitaire-chess).

**Rules:**

> 1. Pieces move as in regular chess
> 2. Every move must be a capture
> 3. When there is only 1 piece left, you win.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution is:

> Nxd2 Bxc2 Rxd3 Rxd2 Rxc2 Nxc2 Nxa1

As images:

> [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Much the same as Tryth - I think this is essentially the only solution.

> Nd2 Rd3 Rd2 Rc2 Bc2 Nc2 Na1

which I'm just posting to try making a (slightly jumpy) gif...

> [image]

Comment: +1 cool gif. yeah, i tried to create this puzzle with just 1 basic solution (except for a few move order differences) since the 1st Solitaire Chess puzzle had so many different solutions.